# How to print unix tool version in BusyBox container?

Tags: unix, versioning, busybox

I can't figure out how to print (unix tool) versions within a BusyBox container:

```bash
$ docker run -it quay.io/quay/busybox:latest
$ awk --version
awk: unrecognized option `--version'
BusyBox v1.32.0 (2020-08-31 17:40:13 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: awk [OPTIONS] [AWK_PROGRAM] [FILE]...

        -v VAR=VAL      Set variable
        -F SEP          Use SEP as field separator
        -f FILE         Read program from FILE
        -e AWK_PROGRAM
```

```
$ cut --version
cut: unrecognized option `--version'
BusyBox v1.32.0 (2020-08-31 17:40:13 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: cut [OPTIONS] [FILE]...

Print selected fields from each input FILE to stdout

        -b LIST Output only bytes from LIST
        -c LIST Output only characters from LIST
        -d CHAR Use CHAR instead of tab as the field delimiter
        -s      Output only the lines containing delimiter
        -f N    Print only these fields
        -n      Ignored
```

---

Any suggestions? Many mulled containers are built on top of BusyBox, best I get on top of this.

Thanks

Comment: `busybox` is intended for systems with limited storage. It combines small versions of several UNIX tools in one program and does not support all options/functions of the individual tools. See the supported commands and options: https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html. What do you want to achieve by asking for the version?

Comment: Nextflow is very strict when it comes to reporting versions of tools used in a modularised process. I'd just export all tool versions in a .yml file e.g: https://github.com/nf-core/sarek/blob/c87f4eb694a7183e4f99c70fca0f1d4e91750b33/modules/nf-core/cat/cat/main.nf#L45-L48

Answer (score 1):

`busybox` is a single program which acts as one of various tools depending on what name was used to call it. As you can see in the question, it shows its version as `BusyBox v1.32.0`.

Check which tools are (symbolic) links to `busybox`. All these are the same program and therefore have the same version, so you might only need the version of `busybox` and a list of commands linked to it.

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15895/330217 the best way to display the version of `busybox` is

```
busybox | head -1
```

Comment: "All these are the same program and therefore have the same version"


Did not know this - thanks